# Tableau refresh sort order after parameter selection

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard with a line chart and a few bar charts. There are parameter controls for date ranges and customers at the top. The issue I have is that whenever I change one of the parameters, the bar charts lose their sort order. Has anyone been able to correct this so that the sort is applied after parameter selection? Thanks for any help you can provide!

EDIT: I should have specified that I am trying to sort by measure value. I have about 5 measures and would like them to resort descending after the parameter selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sorting by Date or by Customer?

If you're sorting by date, make sure you have the actual Date column on the shelf rather than the parameter. Also, make sure Tableau is seeing both the Date and Date parameter as the "date" data type and not as strings.

If you're sorting by customer, right-click your date on the shelf and make sure your sort is set to the correct field and aggregation like the screenshot below.

If all of that still doesn't work, there's always the option to set the sort manually.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just edited the question to include that I am trying to sort multiple measure values.